# Dynamically Update Xcelsius Dashboard from Excel Data

Tags: excel, xcelsius

I am designing an Xcelsius dashboard that will need to be updated once a week with data that only exists in an Excel Pivot table. I have been able to create dynamic dashboards in the past by tying the dashboard to an XML file or database. I am looking for suggestion on how to dynamically read an Excel File from and Xcelsius dashboard.

Comment: why not dynamical create a new excel file with same file name by java or other  programming  language, then you can dynamically read an Excel file。

Answer (score 1):

Try Centigon Solutions CSV Connector.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your best bet is to save the Excel file as XML and read it back using the XML features via Xcelsius and Excel. If you need some help there are a number of videos that can walk you through the process at both [MyXcelsius](http://myxcelsius.com) and [Datapig Technologies](http://www.datapigtechnologies.com/XcelsiusMain.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a macro in the Excel File that automatically creates the xml file an saves it in the path where the Xcelsisus File reads it from. You will have to program it once and never worry for it again, and its reausable for every dashboard you make.