# How to write data back in embedded spreadsheet in xcelsius after exporting the dashboard as SWF?

Tags: dashboard, business-objects, xcelsius

I don't want to use any external connection. I want to use my embedded spreadsheet of xcelsius as my database. I want to fetch data from it and at the same time I want to store new record into it.

This is all my requirement. Is this possible? If yes please I desperately need some expert guidance to do so.

I have searched a lot for this and I have found lots of stuff. Basically they all are speaking about InfoBurst/Infosol and web-services and many other high end things. I'm very much new in BO and my requirement is also very simple.

Waiting for guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot, at least not natively. You'll either need to use an external connector or a third-party plugin (such as [CSV Connector](http://centigonsolutions.com/csvconnector.html) from Centigon Solutions).

The only way that you can save data natively, is using the scenarios feature as described [here](http://ryangoodman.net/blog/2008/06/08/saving-scenarios-with-xcelsius/). But this is probably not what you are looking for.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489085/dynamically-update-xcelsius-dashboard-from-excel-data) also provides some additional information.

Here's an [additional presentation](http://azbocug.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Write-Back-Dashboards.pdf) regarding write-back dashboards that you might find interesting.

Comment: sir .....those third-party plug-ins I cant buy so that option is closed. I have dug some more deep about this and I have found that with an external connection and web-service this can b done. Is it  possible that I use MS-SQL as my db and I create an universe using that db and on top that I use QAAS to get that done? please reply

Comment: Have a look [here](http://davidlai101.com/blog/2012/01/26/using-xcelsius-and-webservices-to-insert-comments-into-a-database/) for more information using a web service to post data back to the database. This does go against your initial question, so please change the requirements of your original question or create a new question with new requirements (and optionally close this question by accepting the answer).